# Python - List name syntax error

Tags: python, list

hey so ive been working on this truth or dare python game for a while and i never got this problem before, but when i put a list it gives me a syntax error, but only on the NAME of the list. not the actual list itself. Here is the code:

```
import random
import time
import sys

dare = ["try to drink a glass of water while standing on your hands", "Let the group deside your dare", "pose in an embarasing pose and take a picture", "kiss the person on your left", "let a person get your phone and text anyone in your contacts.", "do the worm", "lick the floor", "let the group give you a new hairstyle", "drag your butt on the floor and back", "do yoyr best impression of a baby being born", "let someone in the room give you a spanking", "make up a poem about whatever the group comes up with", "make everyone in the room smile", "let someone draw on your face with a pen"]
d = ["dance with no music for", "curse like a sailor for", "pretend your a clown for", "make up an opera about anyone/anything for", "talk in a different accent for", "break dance for", "do the worm for", "do push ups for", "be someones pet for", "pole dance with an invisible pole for", "sing for", "belly dance for"]
d_time = ["1 turn", "40 seconds", "3 turns", "25 seconds", "1 minute", "4 turns", "2 minutes", "5 minutes", "5 turns"]

t = ["who would you want to make out with the most in the room?", "what was the stupidest thing youve ever done?", " if you were an animal, what would you be?", "if you could dye your hair any color, what would it be?", "what was the scariest dream youve had?", "who is the sexiest person here?", "who do you think would actidentaly kill someone in this room?", "who here has the nicest butt?", "how many lovers have you had?", "what is your biggest pet peeve", "who do you have a crush on atm?"]

print("welcome to Truth or Dare!")
def begin():
    wow = input("[1] Truth, or [2] Dare?")
    if wow == '2':
        ch = random.randint(1, 2)
        if ch == 1:
            print(random.choice(dare))
            time.sleep(1)
            br = input("did you ([1] chiken out?) or ([2] complete it?)")
            if br == '1':
                print("wow...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("thats sad...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Next player!")
                time.sleep(1)
                begin()
            elif br == '2':
                print("wow!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("nice!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Next player!")
                time.sleep(1)
                begin()
        elif ch == 2:
            print(random.choice(d),(random.choice(d_time))
            time.sleep(1)
            br = input("did you ([1] chiken out?) or ([2] complete it?)")
            if br == '1':
                print("wow...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("thats sad...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Next player!")
                time.sleep(1)
                begin()
            elif br == '2':
                print("wow!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("nice!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Next player!")
                time.sleep(1)
                begin()
    elif wow == '1':
        print(random.choice(t))
        time.sleep(1)
        br = input("did you ([1] chiken out?) or ([2] complete it?)")
            if br == '1':
                print("wow...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("thats sad...")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Next player!")
                time.sleep(1)
                begin()
            elif br == '2':
                print("wow!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("nice!")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Next player!")
                time.sleep(1)
                begin()
begin()
```

the list d is the one getting syntax errored, please help!

Comment: can you post the full Traceback? I cannot reproduce the problem you describe, but I see a few other problems

Comment: Please use the checkmark next to answers to say a question is answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is in:

```
elif ch == 2:
        print(random.choice(d),(random.choice(d_time))    # THIS PART!!!
# You forget to close brackets! > print(random.choice(d),(random.choice(d_time)))
        time.sleep(1)
        br = input("did you ([1] chiken out?) or ([2] complete it?)")
        if br == '1':
            print("wow...")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("thats sad...")
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Next player!")
            time.sleep(1)
            begin()
```

print(random.choice(d),(random.choice(d_time))**)**

Also, you should use an IDE, IDEs tell you this basics errors, or when you forget to close a ], or :. They save you a lot of time searching errors!

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close the bracket ')' in

```
print(random.choice(d),(random.choice(d_time))
```

and properly indent the code and the code will run.